# Podio API - C# - Unable to fetch Items using appitemid

Tags: podio

Trying to fetch the list of Items under an App for a workspace. Able to retrieve workspaces list and the apps under each workspace. But unable to retrieve the items under the space / app. Tried using both 'FilterItems' and 'GetItemByAppItemId', but itemid results in null. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Here's the code,

```
public DataTable GetDeliverables()
    {

        string spaceName = string.Empty;
        var spaceResult = podio.SpaceService.GetOrganizationSpaces(orgID);          
        try
        {              
            foreach (var space in spaceResult)
            {
                var appResult = podio.ApplicationService.GetAppsBySpace(space.SpaceId);
                spaceName = space.Name;

                foreach (var appItem in appResult)
                {
                    if (appItem.Config.ItemName != null)
                    {
                        if (appItem.Config.ItemName.Contains("Deliverable"))
                        {                             
                          var itemResult = podio.ItemService.GetAppValues(appItem.AppId);
                          if (itemResult != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var fields in itemResult.Fields)
                                {
                                    if (fields.Values != null && fields.Values.ToString() != "[]")
                                    {
                                        var values = fields.Values.ToString();
                                        if (values.ToString().Contains("\"title\": \"Marketing\""))
                                        {
                                            /*Get Value*/
                                            JArray jsonArrayForValues = JArray.Parse(values);
                                            var jsonValue = JObject.Parse(jsonArrayForValues[0].ToString());
                                            JObject objValue = JObject.Parse(jsonValue.ToString());
                                            var item = jsonValue.SelectToken("items");
                                            DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
                                            DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
                                            dttable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                         .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Title") == "Marketing")
                                                         .CopyToDataTable();

                                            object app_item_id = dttable.Rows[0]["app_item_id"];
                                            object item_id = dttable.Rows[0]["item_id"];

                                            if (Convert.ToInt32(app_item_id) != 0)
                                            {
                                                var dataForAppItem = podio.ItemService.GetItemByAppItemId(appItem.AppId, Convert.ToInt32(app_item_id));
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                      
                }
            }
 DataTable dtnewtable = new DataTable(); 
 return dtnewtable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, make sure that you are handling the rate limits. Also make sure that your podio client have have enough permission for each of the operations in it.

```
public string ExtractUserdata(Podio podioClient)
 {
    var spaces = _podioOperationService.GetSpaces(podioClient, org.OrgId);
    if (spaces?.Any() == true)
    {
        foreach (var space in spaces)
        {        
            var apps = _podioOperationService.GetApps(podioClient, space.SpaceId);
            if (apps?.Any() == true)
            {
                foreach (var app in apps)
                {      
                   var items = FilterAllPodioItems(app.AppId, podioClient);
                  // Do your operations here

                }
            }
        }
    }     
    return "Success";
}

public List<Item> FilterAllPodioItems(int appid, Podio podioClient)
{
    var allFilterItems = new List<Item>();
    try
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int limit = 500;
        bool continueOperation = true;

        do
        {
            var filteredItems = podioClient.ItemService.FilterItems(appId: appid, limit: limit, offset: offset);
            if (filteredItems.Items?.Any() == true)
            {
                allFilterItems.AddRange(filteredItems.Items);
            }
            offset = offset + limit;
            if (filteredItems == null || filteredItems.Filtered <= offset)
            {
                continueOperation = false;
            }
        } while (continueOperation);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return allFilterItems;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but we are still getting null values for both FilterItems and GetItemByAppItemId. What permissions do we need to retrieve Items data. Where and how do I check if my login has these permissions?

Comment: If you are using App authenticated podio client then there will be no restrictions, but if you are using user authenticated podio client you need access to the app items.

Comment: Thanks Akbar, Can you please let me know how to check the access permissions?

Comment: Web API is almost same as web UI. If the user have access to the item through the browser, you can get it through API using the same user's credentials.

Or you can use app authentication, So you don't have to worry about the permission issues. you can read more about it in here https://developers.podio.com/authentication